# BeautifulSoup: extract between href and class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to store the dates from the following chunk of text:

```
newsoup = '''<html><body><a href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3460">Proclamation 
of Pardons in Western Pennsylvania (July 10, 1795)</a>, <a class="transcript" href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3460">Transcript</a>, 
<a href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3939">Seventh Annual Message to Congress (December 8, 1795)</a></body></html>'''
```

But, I'm having trouble getting at the text between `>` and `</a>`. Once I get `Proclamation of Pardons in Western Pennsylvania (July 10, 1795)`, I'll be set. I've tried adapting another approach to my specific data, but I end up with an empty object.

I'm trying something like the following, but having little luck:

```
a = newsoup.findAll('a',attrs={'href'})
print a
```

I should have noted that `newsoup` was already a soup object.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming newsoup is a soup object, I think this should work:

(If it is not, you can run `newsoup = BeautifulSoup(newsoup)` )

```
a = newsoup.findAll('a')
for x in a:
    print x.text
```

Comment: Hmm, docs I found called the method get_text() but I came to the same conclusion.  The "href" keyword argument is also not needed, because it is supposed to filter links by a specific href (Which was not even provided)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
a = newsoup.findAll('a')[0].contents[0]
```

where `newsoup` is a BeautifulSoup object.

Or else first do:

```
newsoup = BeautifulSoup(newsoup)
```

You can put that in a loop:

```
a = soup.findAll('a')
for x in a:
    print x.contents[0]
```